# Result in an argument isn't correct

Tags: recursion, prolog

So I have this piece of prolog code:

```
my_avalia(A, R) :-
    A == "Koza" -> koza(R, 0, 0, e, 89).

koza(R, _, _, _, 87) :-
    !,
    write(R).

koza(R, X, Y, V, C) :-
    movex(V, X, X1),
    movey(V, Y, Y1),
    confirma(X1, Y1, Z),
    Z == 1 -> (append(R, [emFrente], U),
            L is (C - 1),
            koza(U, X1, Y1, V, L)).
```

The matter is that when I write the "R" at koza(), it has the correct values, however it ends up with a empty list in my_avalia when I call it like this:

my_avalia("Koza",R).

My recursion might be incorrect but I don't really know what's wrong with it.
Thanks in advance.

The other functions:

```
movex(X,Y,R):-(X==o)->(R is Y-1).
movex(X,Y,R):-(X==n)->(R is Y).
movex(X,Y,R):-(X==s)->(R is Y).
movex(X,Y,R):-(X==e)->(R is Y+1).

movey(X,Y,R):-(X==n)->(R is Y-1).
movey(X,Y,R):-(X==s)->(R is Y+1).
movey(X,Y,R):-(X==o)->(R is Y).
movey(X,Y,R):-(X==e)->(R is Y).

confirma(X,Y,R):-(santafe(X,Y),R is 1); (R is 0).
```

**I figured it out.. Such a silly mistake.**

```
koza([], _, _, _, 87) :-!.
koza(R, X, Y, V, C) :-
    movex(V, X, X1),
    movey(V, Y, Y1),
    confirma(X1, Y1, Z),
    Z == 1 -> (L is (C - 1),
            koza(U, X1, Y1, V, L),
            append(U, [emFrente], R)).
```

**Thanks anyway.**

Comment: where does emFrente comes from ?

Comment: This is supposed to be an algorithm that generates orders to an ant. Those orders are the correct actions in order to make the ant pick all the food in a trail. I've only included part of the function but you get the idea. By the way, "emFrente" means "go straight ahead" in my language.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your problem but it seems to me that you could simplify your movex and movey predicates with a syntax like movex(o, Y, R) :- R is Y -1. etc... The same stands for your my_avalia predicate.

Comment: @PauloNunes Post your solution as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
koza([], _, _, _, 87) :-!.
koza(R, X, Y, V, C) :-
    movex(V, X, X1),
    movey(V, Y, Y1),
    confirma(X1, Y1, Z),
    Z == 1 -> (L is (C - 1),
            koza(U, X1, Y1, V, L),
            append(U, [emFrente], R)).
```